# Swift variable declaration trouble

Tags: swift, syntax, declaration

I'm following a guide that use this syntax to declare a variable:

```
let fromView = presenting ? toView : transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextFromViewKey)
```

But I don't understand the syntax: specially the question mark and the colon (`presenting`  is a boolean variable).

Comment: Sorry if I've made some mistakes with the language, I'm italian.

Comment: Have a look at the section of the [ternary (conditional) operator in the language reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html). This is in essence an inline `if` statement: if boolean variable `presenting` is `true`, then `fromView` will be assigned `toView`, whereas otherwise (if `presenting` is `false`), `fromView` will be assigned `transitionContext.view(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This allows you to declare variables based on boolean expressions. It saves time as you don't have to write out various if else statements. The above expression in your question is declaring the variable based on the boolean presenting. If presenting is true then fromView gets set to toView (on left side of colon). If presenting is false, then fromView gets set to transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextFromViewKey) or right side of the colon